# ASP.net Tree-->SiteMap Skip the Root Node

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I am using Ext.net TreePanel which does not have an option to skip the root node.

Basically, I have the following code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SiteMapNode siteNode = SiteMap.RootNode;
    Ext.Net.TreeNode root = this.CreateNode(siteNode);
    root.Draggable = false;
    root.Expanded = true;
    TreePanel1.Root.Add(root);
}

private Ext.Net.TreeNode CreateNode(SiteMapNode siteMapNode)
{

    Ext.Net.TreeNode treeNode = new Ext.Net.TreeNode();

    treeNode.NodeID = siteMapNode.Key;
    treeNode.Text = siteMapNode.Title;
    treeNode.Qtip = siteMapNode.Description;


    SiteMapNodeCollection children = siteMapNode.ChildNodes;

    if (children != null && children.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (SiteMapNode mapNode in siteMapNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            treeNode.Nodes.Add(this.CreateNode(mapNode));
        }
    }
    return treeNode;
}
```

Could you please help to skip the parent node in the above example.

Thank you and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Root Node is required, although you can set `RootVisible="false"` on your `<ext:TreePanel />` to hide it.

Hope this helps.